# Get text range of link in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a UITextView that contains a link and some other text. The link detection is enabled and working (iOS8). However, I am at loss to find the range of the link within the textView.

The idea is that the text is scanned (after link detection is done) and the link preloaded into a web view, so that when a user taps on an element somewhere, the web view can reveal itself.

How can I get the range of the detected link within a UITextView?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to preload it?

Comment: How did you put the link into the `NSAttributedString`? You can enumarate the attributes of your `NSAttributedString` and find the one with the `NSLinkAttributeName`. But are you looking for its range or the link URL behind it?

Comment: @AdamPro13 To reduce delay into opening it locally, rather than opening safari and viewing it there.

@ Larme The link was automatically detected by UITextView, I did not create the attributed string. Is there a way I can retroactively enumerate the attributed string?

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for the link, the range I figured is a step to extract it from the text

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:
is it possible to use this to look for the link? But then what does a link attributed look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it, is to use [`enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:), where from my example `attr` is `[yourTextView attributedText]`.

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *ranges = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attr enumerateAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                 inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attr length])
                 options:0
              usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Attribute: %@, %@", value, NSStringFromRange(range));
                  if (value)
                      [ranges setObject:value forKey:[NSValue valueWithRange:range]];
}];
NSLog(@"Ranges: %@", ranges);
```

I kept the range too, just in case, but you could use a `NSArray` with all the different links instead of a `NSDictionary`.

**EDIT:**
From your comments, I may assume that the link you mentioned are there because of the `NSDataDetector`. In a few words, it will detect from `NSString` if there is something like: "http://www.randomSite.com". You can read about `NSDataDetector` to get more info about it (it can detect phone numbers, mail adresses etc.), the `UITextView` often detect some by defaults.
So the `NSAttributedString` may not incorporate the `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute.

So a work around (this time, I just kept the link, but I guess you know how to do if you want something like previous solution with the range too):

```
NSString *stringWithNSDataDetector = [yourTextView text];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector * dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink
                                                                error:&error];
//Check if (error) before
__block NSMutableArray *allMatches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dataDetector enumerateMatchesInString:stringWithNSDataDetector
                           options:0
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringWithNSDataDetector length])
                        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
        [allMatches addObject:[match URL]];
}];
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome, I just got time to try this out I will let you know, but a quick test says it does exactly what I need

Comment: This answers exactly what I need. Thank you! Although by data detector you mean attributed string? There is no method for NSDataDetector

Comment: @MichaelLorenzo: I Added more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you're aiming to do something like how Twitter opens links in tweets, do the following:

1. Set the delegate for your `UITextView` to your view controller.
2. Implement the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` in your view controller. This will get called when the user selects the link in the text view. In the method, you will want to `return NO`. However, before returning NO you should create a new view controller that has a web view and load the web view with the URL that gets passed in as a parameter.

This doesn't do the preloading like you mentioned, but I'm not sure if you're doing it for a specific reason (like you want the web view to display alongside the text view) or you want to do it just because you think there will be a performance advantage once the user taps the link.

Comment: This is a great answer. Yeah it is mainly that the link isn't the only target area. I'm designing something similar to a mobilized Reddit so I want to rely on something like a whole tableviewcell to open it as well.