# How can I conclude a specific range in a textview is a link?

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsdatadetector

I have the location/range the user tapped. I need now to understand if this is a link or not (data detectors are enabled). Is there a way to do that?

Thank you...

Comment: Don't think it is anymore complex than testing if word begins with either http:// or https://

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595378/get-text-range-of-link-in-uitextview/28595578#28595578 on the range the user tapped. But `textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction)` delegate method should be called too.

Comment: @Spads that's true but it won't solve other detectable data such as address, dates etc

Comment: When the text gets entered, scan it and store the ranges of the links you are interested in. Then when the user taps, you only have to see if the tap is in one of those ranges.