# How to enumerate UITextView accessibility child elements?

Tags: ios, uitextview, accessibility, nsattributedstring, accessibility-inspector

I have a `UITextView` that displays attributed string with links in it. When I run Accessibility Inspector, it can correct detect the `UITextView` as static text, and list the links as children with correct `UIAccessibilityTraitLink`. Now I need to get those elements from my own code. But `UITextView` doesn't return any of the inner accessibility elements. What interface does Accessibility Inspector go through to find the child elements? The attached screenshot is what Accessibility Inspector sees:

[image]

Comment: "But UITextView doesn't implement any of the UIAccessibilityContainer methods" What do you mean by "doesn't implement"?

Comment: @matt [textView accessibilityElementCount] returns 0x7fffffffffffffff and [textView accessibilityElements] returns nil

Comment: Okay, but that is "implementing" them. It implements them to return zero and nil, but it implements them. — I'm having trouble figuring out where you see the links as children in the Accessibility Inspector.

Comment: @matt I rephrased my question and attached Accessibility Inspector screenshot.

Comment: It's funny, I just don't see that on my machine.

Comment: Do you add a link to the attributed string?

Comment: I'm running Accessibility Inspector 5.0 and iOS simulator.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Find all the links? If you use `NSAttributedString` or `NSDataDetector`, it's possible, no use to go with Accessibilty that seems to higlight them in the inspector. You can get then the Text that is marked as a link, and the URL attached. See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595378/get-text-range-of-link-in-uitextview/28595578#28595578